# LCR circuits with changing input frequencies

Tags: fourier, lcr

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fXOWl6.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Ok, imagine an LCR circuit with a resonant frequency ***f*** connected to a signal generator inputting a sine wave. The signal generator starts it's input at a frequency far lower than ***f***. Over a short period of time, the signal generator slews up to a frequency far greater than ***f***.

If you were to measure the phase difference between the current and voltage, of course you see the current lag during the inductive portion and you see it lead during the capacitive portion. Note that if the frequency was static, the frequency of the current and voltage are the same. However, in this scenario, the relationship goes from current lagging, to it being in phase at the instant it is at the resonant frequency then to it leading voltage.

It seems to therefore follow that the current and voltage cannot have the same frequency if their phase relationship differs over time with the changing of input frequency over time.

First off, what are your thoughts on this? Is there an error in my logic that means the frequencies have to be the same? Secondly, if the frequencies do in fact differ, why is it so? My intuition tells me that it would be easily solved with a Fourier Transform, but I tried doing so and I just am not good enough to do it.

Comment: Rather than ask us to imagine a circuit, why not provide a schematic so we know we're all imagining the same circuit and our answers will make sense.

Comment: Edit your question and add your circuit.  In toolbar, you will see a circuit with a pencil.  Click on it and it will open up an editor, which is pretty simple.  When you finish, you can add it to your question under File - Save And Insert.

Comment: As the elements are in series **the current is common** (same phase in R,C and L)  so its the voltage that is out of phase across the inductor and the capacitor. As VC and VL are always 180 degrees out of phase the result is simply the difference between them.

Answer (score 0):

Have you written the vector summation of the reactances, and of the voltages, in a series LRC circuit. Since it is series, the current is the SAME in all 3 components.

Here is a series LRC, with the frequency+phase plotted +- 1 decade (left plot) and +- 1% (right plot).

I think you are considering a high-Q (narrow bandwidth) high-stored-energy circuit, where the external stimulus frequency conflicts with the resonant frequency (energy is only stored by having alternate magnetic and electric fields performing the energy storage, thus energy sloshes back and forth between inductor and capacitor, every 90 degrees.)

[image]

Now lets look at this, in the time domain. Take a high-Q circuit (low R) resonant at 300MHz, but hit the circuit with edges repeating at 39MHz. (welcome to Signal Wave Explorer) The energy fighting is stunningly obvious. By the way, you *can* see these effects in the lab.

[image]

To see this on your own computer, in SWE, click on topleft "examples" and select the "scope probe ringing" example. Then click on "trapezoid", near the topleft, enter that popup menu and change the frequency to 39MHz. Click save. Now drop to bottom of main screen, and click "use FFT". Then click "run".
In 2 seconds, you get a display. At topleft, edit "spacing" [default is 5] to be 0 (zero). Click "update/reset".